# Twitter bootstrap multiple divs on one row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

CSS noob here. I want to divs in the same row.  Using some twitter bootstrap CSS I do:

```
.row-fluid {
   width: 100%;
   *zoom: 1;
}

.span6{
  width: 460px;
}

.row-fluid .span6 {
   width: 48.717948717948715%;
   *width: 48.664757228587014%;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  height: 5em;
}
```

and my HTML is...

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6">Foo</div>
<div class="span6">Bar</div>
</div>
```

the Foo and Bar are not one the one line.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFgTA/

Thanks.

Comment: What's the extra css there? Is that stuff you changed or is that standard bootstrap? The reason I ask is because it seems to work fine, as long as bootstrap is there. http://bootply.com/74478

Comment: @brbcoding Not sure - Looking at some code here that I don't have complete control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you actually using the twitter bootstrap or are you copying parts of it?  You only have a small fraction of the css that actually defines the `row-fluid` functionality.  For example, the first element normally has it's margins changes to account for the extra pixels an element has around it and all the elements that have a `span*` class assigned to them are supposed to `float: left` like mentioned by mshsayem.

If you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/cFgTA/2/), which uses a CDN bootstrap and your code commented out, there are no issues.  I recommend you use the actual css file provided by twitter unless you are familiar with their stylesheet & css to make changes to it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know bootstrap; but it seems you missed a `float:left` on `.row-fluid .span6.` Check if this is ok: http://jsfiddle.net/cFgTA/1